# Java Script trouble with loops

Tags: javascript, loops, dice

I've just started learning Java Script and I was having trouble with loops. I'm trying to make a program that rolls a die 100 times and prints out the results. When I run this program, it prints out one roll 100 times, instead of printing out each roll once. Could anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
function start(){
var roll = Randomizer.nextInt(1 , 6);
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ){
    roll;
    println("you rolled a " + roll);
}




}
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Put the Randomizer call inside the loop. `roll;` by itself doesn't do anything. (Also, try to give your questions a more specific title than "trouble with x".)

Comment: `roll;` does nothing. it's just a statement. If you want to pull another random number you need to actually call the function that generates the random number `Randomizer.nextInt(1,6)`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run "roll" each time the loop is happening, so instead of just `roll;` you'll need to have `roll = Randomizer.nextInt(1 , 6);` inside the loop as well.

Or a better practice (since you're learning, it could help better your understanding), create a function called `roll()` and save what the function returns to a `result` variable, then print `result` out.

```
function roll () {
    return Randomizer.nextInt(1 , 6);
}

function start () {
    var result;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        result = roll();
        println('you rolled a ' + result);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps you understand how to call a function to roll the dice again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dice = function() {
  var roll = 1,
    counter = 0,
    LIMIT = 100,
    DIE_TOP = 6,
    result = [];
  for (; counter < LIMIT; counter++, roll = Math.floor((Math.random() * DIE_TOP) + 1)) result.push(roll);
  return result;
};

var test = dice();
document.write(test);
```